# Boostrap 5 - can't disable collapse with stopPropagation() when clicking on a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to disable the collapse/expansion of an element when I click a checkbox within it.

For the example I have on codepen, **my code worked with Boostrap v4**, but with v5, the stopPropagation function seems to be ignored.

See here - https://codepen.io/s89_/pen/oNyKbYE

I ***could*** wrap the click functionality into a div that doesn't wrap around the input checkbox but I'd like the entire row width to be clickable so disabling event propagation seems easier.

HTML:-

```
<div id="collapse-example">
  <div class="card col-6" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" id="custom-input">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Loreum ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const input = document.getElementById('custom-input')
    input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add data-bs-toggle="collapse" to the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="custom-input" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="collapse-example">
  <div class="card col-6" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" data-bs-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" id="custom-input" data-bs-toggle="collapse" >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Loreum ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh - that works, thanks!  This is effectively cancelling out the collapse right?  It works but it seems a little hacky?

Comment: Yes, it instantly undoes the toggle just done, rather than prevents it. But no JS needed to stop propagation, so very economical. A more pure way would be to create a checkbox outside the container and position it absolutely over it, but also protecting the space where it appears from being filled by the container contents. Semantically, this would protect its independent identity.